# jQuery Mobile: Page hangs after inactivity

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

We use jQuery Mobile and always the same error appears - only on mobile devices.
After a time of inactivity it is not possible to call a page by clicking a link. Also a reload does not work. After this "hang" the browser skip the call by prompting a network error. Then you can reload and it works fluid. 
If you navigate without a delay from three minutes or up, all is working fine. 
Does anybody have an idea about this error?